# HTML object tag covering too much space

Tags: html, object, reference

My problem is my header, which is referenced through an object tag, takes up too much space.  I have added a border to show where is is.  The only reason this matters is you cannot click anything inside the object tag boundry.
CSS:

```
#nav_obj {
    width:100%;
    /*height:100%;*/
    z-index:999;
    padding:0;
    position: sticky;
    top:-16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<object type="text/html" id="nav_obj" data="header.html">Header</object>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m8e0.png)

Comment: what is the need for object tag

Comment: @rahulmr to incorporate the header into the page file.